# Showcases of conlangs

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I thought it'd be good to have a page for showcases of conlangs [like Code Golf SE does](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44680/89459), so here I go. (This post is mostly plagiarized from the linked post.)

This thread is dedicated to showing off interesting, useful, obscure, and/or unique features your favorite constructed languages have to offer. This is neither a challenge nor a competition, but a collaboration effort to showcase as many constructed languages as possible as well as possible.

## How this works

- All answers should include the name of the constructed language at the top of the post, prefixed by a #.
- Answers may contain one (and only one) factoid, i.e., a couple of English sentences without actual demonstrations of the constructed language.
- Aside from the factoid, answers should consist of demonstrations of the constructed language.
- The demonstrations do not need to be related. In fact, demonstrations that are too related may be redundant.
- Since this is not a contest, all constructed languages are welcome, whenever they were created.
- Whenever possible, there should be only one answer per constructed language. **The answer must be posted as a community wiki**, so users would feel free to add demonstrations to any answer, even if they haven't created it themself.

Answers that predate these guidelines should be edited. Please help updating them as needed.